# Autohotkey - ending a script early

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to end a script early, i.e. to jump to the bottom of the code?

My script is something like:

```
F9::
Goto, F10 
sendinput {enter}
sendinput Hello!
sendinput {enter}
Sleep 1000
sendinput {enter}
sendinput What can I do for you?
sendinput {enter}
F10:
return
```

I would like to jump to the `X` within the script for `F9`, by pressing a certain key (maybe `F10`). Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

*Note:* I do not want to end the script via `ExitApp`. I want to retain it somehow if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`goto`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Goto.htm) statement which you can use to "jump" to another part of the code.

Example:

```
Goto, X
...
X:
Sleep, 100
...
```

Comment: Ok and where do I have to define `Goto`? Inside the `F9` environment or elsewhere?

Comment: Place it at the spot that you want to jump.  Maybe you would have `F10::` and then `Goto, X`

Comment: see my edited code. Your tip does not work, because it always ends my script immediately instead of doing that as an option. I am sorry that the original question did not reflect this.

Comment: @TomM: You need an If condition there!

Comment: @tumchaaditya I understand. Could you help me how to do that?

Comment: I will have to do a little testing before posting an answer.